# Why use HTML 5 over HTML 4?

Tags: html

I have just rewritten my personal resume web page in HTML 5 and I like the simpler, less cryptic syntax of the head part of the markup.

But apart from that, what are advantages of HTML 5 over the good old HTML 4.01? As far as I know, there is no support for HTML 5 in legacy browsers (Internet Explorer earlier version than 9) and because many people still use those browsers, I would still have to use flash workarounds for video tag or similar HTML 5 features. It seems just like a lot more work than just to use HTML 4.01.

Comment: You mean, "there is no support for HTML5 in legacy..."

Comment: Because you aren't programming only for today but even for tomorrow? If everyone did as you suggest, everyone would still program for DOS.

Comment: I personally wouldn't hire any developer that didn't use HTML5 on their resume site.

Comment: @Philip And perhaps a bank wouldn't hire any developer that DID use HTML5 :-) In the end the "war" between progressists and conservatives goes on.

Comment: A "less cryptic syntax" then HTML5? How is that possible? Just don't stuff any element you've found in the spec into your markup. Only use whats appropriate…

Comment: @feeela I meant HTML 5 has less cryptic syntax. For example doctype, meta tags, link tags etc are less cryptic than in HTML 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML5 is not something that is supported or isn't supported.

It's not even a complete specification yet. Browsers may or may not support some of HTML5 features. Legacy browsers may have no support at all for newer features introduced with HTML5. As long as you don't use any of the new features introducted in HTML5, your document will be compatible with legacy browsers too.

If you plan to use some of the new features not supported by legacy browsers, and at the same time making them compatible with your site, you need to choose a different method to display your content.

If you want to make HTML5 compatible with most browsers, I suggest you to use some good tools, like [Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Also, I really suggest to read [this explanation](http://diveintohtml5.info/) about HTML 5.

To get the most out of HTML 5, I have linked many good resources in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399016/html5-where-to-start/7399075#7399075).

Comment: Hello Jose, the link to explanation in the last line of your answer is not functional any more. Could you please fix that?

Comment: @eeerahul: Thanks, fixed broken link and added a link to another answer with many useful HTML 5 resources.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [backwards compatibilty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674655/how-to-write-backwards-compatible-html5) and [graceful degradation](http://www.sitepoint.com/progressive-enhancement-graceful-degradation-basics/). You write your pages with the latest and greatest html version and ensure - with some tricks - that older browsers render the pages properly.

Answer (score 1):

> - Advantage #1: One version of the app caters to clients
>     across multiple platforms (iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows etc).
> - Advantage #2: HTML5-based apps provide 24-7 reliability.
> - Advantage #3: HTML5-based apps provide a strong visual
>     interface.
> - Advantage #4: HTML5 specifications let you employ an agile development
>     process.
> - Advantage #5: HTML5 specifications provide optimum functionality for most apps.
> - Advantage #6: If the specifications are used the right way, HTML5-
>     based apps are secure.

You can read the whole blog post at: [Six Advantages of Developing Cross-Platform HTML5-based Financial Apps](http://www.xignite.com/market-data/6-advantages-of-developing-cross-platform-html5-based-financial-apps-part-1/)